# ActionScript 3 when you move mouse to a direction press a key

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, onmousemove

I'm new to AS3 and i don't know how do i make that when i move my mouse in Action Script to press a key?
For example i want when im moving my mouse to:
-Right : press x
-Left : press z
-Up : press q
-Down : press e
Only while moving the mouse when the mouse its not moving it should do nothing.
And on click : Space
I have tried searching on google methods but i haven`t found methods good for what i need

Comment: **AS3** doesn't have the required level of access to the system to emulate a system-wide keypress. Then, you **CAN** emulate the **AS3**-level keypress event, but what's the point if you can just call the keypress handler methods directly, bypassing the emulation part. With that, I encourage you to elaborate on explaining what is the end goal here.

Comment: i saw some FlashPlayer AS3 games that can do something like this

Comment: Please elaborate on the part, how did you figure out that *moving mouse to a direction presses a key* in some Flash games?

Comment: Well there was a game called Tanki Online that was in FlashPlayer 11 but they moved few weeks ago to HTML5 completly.